# Why is the attribute size of h:selectManyListbox redefined in Google chrome?

Tags: html, jsf, google-chrome

I have some problem using JSF `<h:selectManyListbox>` and Google Chrome.

When my page is loading an error "Attribute size redefined" appears. 
I just want to see only 5 items in my list box:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="usersManyListbox" value="#{pingResultBean.selectedUsers}"
 size="5" style="width:168px;">
        <f:selectItems value="#{pingResultBean.userItems}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

In other browsers everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the mentioned attribute appeared twice in the generated HTML source. Rightclick the page in your browser and locate the HTML generated by `<h:selectManyListbox>`. It should look like

```
<select name="formId:usersManyListbox" multiple="multiple" size="5">
```

It should have only one `size` attribute. If it *do* have two or more, then it's likely a bug in the JSF impl/version used. Consider upgrading to the latest version or switching to a different impl.

I can at least *not* reproduce this on Mojarra 1.2_15 and Mojarra 2.1.0.